# Creating column values based on date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, datetime-format

I have a view that has the following columns

```
requested_delivery (DateTime field but time part is always 00:00:00)
product
qty
```

I want to create columns for `Today`, `Today+1`, `Today+2` etc which either have the `qty` in the field if the `requested_delivery` field matches or 0 if it does not

Columns in  view would be

```
requested_delivery, product, qty, Today, Today+1, Today+2
```

Comment: requested_delivery field matches what?? Could you please clarify logic for your new fields?

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you want conditional aggregation:

```
select
   requested_delivery
   ,product
   ,Today = sum(case cast(requested_delivery as date) = cast(getdate() as date) then qty end)
   ,Today+1 = sum(case cast(requested_delivery as date) = dateadd(day,1,cast(getdate() as date)) then qty end)
   ,Today+2 = sum(case cast(requested_delivery as date) = dateadd(day,2,cast(getdate() as date)) then qty end)
from yourView
```

If the goal is to show all items for today AND tomorrow in the Today+1 field, i.e. a rolling number or cumulative, then you can use this:

```
select
   requested_delivery
   ,product
   ,Today = sum(case cast(requested_delivery as date) = cast(getdate() as date) then qty end)
   ,Today+1 = sum(case cast(requested_delivery as date) between cast(getdate() as date) and dateadd(day,1,cast(getdate() as date)) then qty end)
   ,Today+2 = sum(case cast(requested_delivery as date) between between cast(getdate() as date) and dateadd(day,2,cast(getdate() as date)) then qty end)
from yourView
```